# Haskell Snap Framework configuring custom logging?

Tags: haskell, logging, logstash, haskell-snap-framework

I want to implement custom logging in my Snap application so that I can pass my logs as JSON to Logstash / Kibana however I cannot figure out how to override the default logging behaviour.

Reading the code, I'm pretty sure that the [logA (A for Access log) method is what is providing this logging format implicitly](https://github.com/snapframework/snap-server/blob/master/src/Snap/Http/Server.hs#L126).

But I'm not sure how to override it. How do you override the custom logging in the snap framework? Is it impossible? Will I need to raise a PR? Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have asked the Snap Core team if this was possible and the answer is: **no, you cannot configure custom logging**. Raised a feature request as a result which you [can view here](https://github.com/snapframework/snap-server/issues/62#issuecomment-67252909).